# Plotting 12 monthly time series data: builtin `graphics::plot()` gives 'cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"'

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I want to plot 12 different monthly time series data over the year range 1984-2018. I want to get a graph like the following but [`graphics::plot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.html) always gives me an error - what's the solution?

Code:

```
datats <- ts(data, start=c(1984,1), end=c(2018,12), frequency=12)
plot(datats, ylab="PPT_MM")
```

Error:

```
Error in plotts(x = x, y = y, plot.type = plot.type, xy.labels = xy.labels,  : 
cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"
```

Plot: [image of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcIzM.png)

My data:

```
    data<-structure(list(Year = 1984:2018, X1 = c(24.2, 5.3, 59, 31.7, 
93.7, 133.2, 42.8, 29.3, 12, 256.5, 0, 28.5, 22.4, 3.8, 295.4, 
16.1, 7, 244.8, 79.5, 31.6, 45.1, 12.2, 14, 61.4, 117.4, 74.2, 
51, 9.1, 0, 50.4, 0, 13.3, 45.1, 20.7, 25.7), X2 = c(0, 110.5, 
0, 0, 13.8, 4, 23.2, 13.3, 6.1, 84.9, 103.5, 83.3, 56.5, 0, 219.4, 
2.2, 0, 0, 7.5, 17.2, 47.9, 19.2, 20.5, 44.8, 7.3, 26.3, 64.1, 
71.8, 4.6, 0, 80, 16.8, 65.1, 26.2, 2.8), X3 = c(3.4, 78.7, 59.4, 
23.3, 109.3, 51.1, 217.3, 43.5, 5, 60.9, 75.3, 150.1, 73.7, 46, 
118, 121, 52.5, 113, 98.9, 115.2, 83.1, 101.7, 30, 20.5, 73, 
3.2, 241.9, 209.8, 1.6, 113.1, 207.4, 39, 27.4, 15.2, 91.6), 
    X4 = c(51.4, 278.3, 192.4, 56.7, 203.7, 193.7, 251.5, 80.5, 
    192.9, 20.8, 82.4, 49.6, 96.4, 208.5, 123, 113.8, 68.5, 88.9, 
    120.4, 153.2, 121.5, 165.1, 117, 143.9, 129.3, 145.4, 107.9, 
    1, 286.4, 209.3, 44, 55.3, 82.4, 40.3, 83.4), X5 = c(0.6, 
    84.6, 72.7, 39.4, 23.6, 37, 64.9, 57.5, 32, 13.7, 29.8, 33.1, 
    42.8, 21.2, 162.6, 9.8, 15.6, 15.3, 126.6, 133.8, 59.8, 100.5, 
    70, 41.7, 4.5, 29.7, 120.9, 37.7, 112.5, 37.7, 14.8, 34.3, 
    23.2, 35.6, 22.7), X6 = c(0, 0, 5.7, 61.9, 10.1, 0, 5.1, 
    3.1, 1.1, 6.3, 8.2, 0.9, 19.3, 0.5, 38.7, 5, 6.2, 4.3, 1.4, 
    0, 0.7, 0.9, 2, 2.7, 0.3, 5.2, 1.7, 0, 36.9, 0.3, 9.7, 26.3, 
    5.7, 2.2, 2.7), X7 = c(7, 1.4, 0.4, 3.6, 0, 3.8, 0, 1.4, 
    6.8, 0.5, 3.3, 4.1, 2.2, 1.2, 15.4, 2.4, 0.3, 4.3, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1.9, 26.8, 1.3, 0, 2.7, 3.4, 0, 2.7, 13, 6.1, 4.8, 
    5, 3.5), X8 = c(6.4, 1.9, 0.3, 11.6, 3, 14.6, 3.4, 8.9, 0, 
    3.1, 9.9, 3.2, 2.2, 4.3, 2.9, 4.9, 1.8, 2.5, 0.2, 26.3, 0, 
    3.5, 4.7, 5.2, 0.2, 0, 1.3, 0.7, 11.8, 0.6, 32.4, 4.1, 3.8, 
    7.2, 2.8), X9 = c(15.7, 0.2, 0, 0, 15.4, 0.3, 0, 3.4, 0.7, 
    0.6, 4.3, 5.1, 0.7, 0, 1.8, 0, 2.3, 0, 8.8, 21.5, 1, 1, 3, 
    4.3, 9.1, 1.2, 0.6, 5.9, 0, 2.5, 13.6, 3, 3.4, 6.8, 2.22), 
    X10 = c(154.4, 56, 2.6, 0.3, 33.5, 96.9, 48.8, 46.5, 31, 
    26, 110.9, 103.7, 0, 83.2, 3.3, 20.6, 41, 7.3, 21.2, 31.8, 
    47.6, 10.2, 14.5, 18.3, 23.9, 41.3, 32.1, 50.2, 22.3, 64, 
    25.4, 17.2, 7.4, 23.6, 87.6), X11 = c(211.2, 75.1, 180.8, 
    93.5, 120.8, 106, 208.5, 119.9, 141.2, 150.8, 406.3, 46, 
    187.7, 270.3, 113.9, 257, 189.8, 169, 144.3, 121.1, 161.3, 
    125, 117.2, 127.9, 122.8, 34.4, 116, 180.3, 119.7, 1024.7, 
    104.8, 104.5, 51.5, 38.2, 206.8), X12 = c(341.4, 121, 127.2, 
    12, 180.2, 129.5, 110.2, 156.7, 186.2, 67.3, 143.7, 87.6, 
    1.5, 177.3, 15.8, 108.6, 98.8, 43.6, 182.4, 24.1, 89.5, 100.5, 
    95, 82.4, 44.9, 127.1, 59.6, 28.2, 73.2, 919.5, 0, 122.9, 
    51.4, 17.9, 249.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-35L))
```

Comment: Hey @Stackuser, It would be nice for this question and future ones you provide some data (even random). By the information you gave, I would try to take the transpose of your data before ts function:

datats<-ts(t(data),start=c(1984,1),end = c(2018,12),frequency = 12)

 ... Give a try!

Comment: Please use `dput(head(data))` rather than `head(data)`, so we get reproducible data, not just a text dump without types etc. Also, your error message says `Error in plotts` but your code says you're doing `plot()` - please correct whichever is wrong.

Comment: And when you say you want to plot monthly time series data on an annual chart(?), do you mean you first want to add an aggregate step where you aggregate total sales (by year, i.e. take rowsums of your dataframe?) or else by month, over distinct years? If so, please see existing duplicate questions which solve that using base R, dplyr, datatable, tidyverse, etc. Because obviously plot is current objecting to getting (2018-1984+1) = 35 separate timeseries.

Comment: I edited based on your suggestion and I also attached the plot that I want to get and the attached error is exactly what I got in r studio.

Comment: @AdelmoFilho.. it doesn't work!

Comment: Ok so your issue is simply that your input is
 a dataframe of 35 years x 12 months, but want to plot all 420 values as one single series (over the range 1/1984-12/2018). That reduces to how do you reshape/melt a dataframe into a single series/column, which is a duplicate of many existing questions on SO.

Comment: Ok my fourth guess at what you want (based on your graphs and comments) is you want to plot each of the 12 individual monthly series over the 35 years, i.e. 12 series on one chart? Yes or no? We're not mindreaders... The error *"can't plot more than 10 series"* with base `plot` is simply that it sucks, that's why everyone uses other libraries like ggplot2. Also, a fallback is to do faceting (by month or quarter). (Must you really have 12 individual series on one graph, or will you settle for 4 quarterly series (e.g. Jan-Mar, ... Oct-Dec?))

Comment: You got it right @smci and I understood that plot functions sucks for more than 10 series! I wanted 12 individual monthly series over the 35 years and thanks@Adelmo Filho for your great consideration!

Comment: I edited this to make clear that [`graphics::plot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.html)  is the cause of your frustration, not your code. Better to say "`graphics::plot()` always gives an error with 12 series" rather than the overly general "it always gives an error". So don't use `graphics::plot()` again, except for simple/toy cases.

Comment: @smci, okay, but, I still don't get what I want even if I use different other kinds as per your suggestion and if you can, I am happy if you show me by drawing the graph!

Comment: @Stackuser: I'm advising you how to ask your question better - once you phrase the question more clearly, better answers will magically appear :) Please try to avoid writing vague, over-general symptom descriptions like  "it always gives an error" - it takes time and energy to decode. Be specific about what "it" is. Now if you also tried ggplot2 and also got an error, then please post that code and error here (and edit the title again).

Answer (score 1):

Function documentation (https://rdrr.io/r/stats/plot.ts.html) gives us some hints...

Apparently it is not possible to plot more than 10 charts on the same panel. Try for example:

```
datats <- ts(data[,-1], start=c(1984,1), end=c(2018,12), frequency=12)
plot(datats[,c(1:10)], ylab="PPT_MM")
```

[image]

It works! Then to use this method 10 looks like to be a limit.

You can use alternatively some ggplot:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

melt(data, id.vars = "Year") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value , group = 1)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(. ~  variable)
```

[image]